# Show available if the date if the date is not booked yet full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using full calendar, and I want to show available text on those cells which have not booked yet.

```
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
                drop: function() {
                },
                eventLimit: true, // for all non-TimeGrid views
                views: {
                    timeGrid: {
                        eventLimit: 1 // adjust to 4 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
                    }
                },
                events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: base_path+'/available-time',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: $('#form').serialize()+ "&start="+ start.format() +"&end=" + end.format(),
                        success: function(doc) {
                            callback(doc.data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventRender: function(event, element){
                    if($('#start_time').val()){
                        var eventStart = moment(event.start);
                        var eventEnd = event._end === null ? eventStart : moment(event.end);
                        var diffInDays = eventEnd.diff(eventStart, 'days');
                        $("td[data-date='" + eventStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "']").css("background-color", "pink");;
                        for(var i = 1; i < diffInDays; i++) {
                            eventStart.add(1,'day');
                            $("td[data-date='" + eventStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "']").css("background-color", "pink");
                        }
                    }
                },
                dayClick:  function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                    var current_date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

                },
            });
```

Here, events contains an array of events with start_datetime, end_datetime, id, title...

I want to show `available` text on the all other cells except the dates which are on events.

Comment: This has been asked before a few times. The short answer is, you can't do it. If you use your browser's element inspector to look at the HTML you'll realise that the grid system you see is a visual trick made up of lots of layers of elements on top of each other. There are no individual cells in which you could place your text.

Comment: But really you don't need to do it. It should be pretty obvious to the user already that the available slots are the ones which don't already have events on them. The visual distinction is quite clear. All you would do by adding text is clutter up the calendar with lots of repetitive data which might actually make it harder to see the slots clearly. You could also add a bit of explanatory text at the side of your calendar if you think it would help.

Comment: P.s. if you need to restrict which slots are actually shown as available you could always use the "businessHours" feature. Or if you need more flexibility, consider using "background events". You can find information about both of these in the documentation.

Comment: P.p.s. a separate note: since you appear to be using fullCalendar 3, there is no such view as "timeGrid". Please ensure you read the correct documentation for your version

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your time. I got it, meanwhile, can I block selectable to those event day which have event. On those cell where I have added `background:pink`. Or popup some notifications when clicked on those day.